# Discord.js getting data from a json file based on an var

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js

This may be a stupid question but i'm trying to get data from a json file based on a variable but it just keeps returning undefined even if it already exists

```js
const { e } = require('../../emojis.json')
var skin = "yellow";
let skin2 = client.emojis.cache.get(e.skin)
```

the json file (e) has the data stored like this

```js
{
    "e": {
    "red": "808107222043328546",
    "blue": "821697709609320448",
    "green": "821698356526841856",
    "pink": "821700492244942888",
    "orange": "821700998799163392",
    "yellow": "821701148628353034",
    "black": "821701297274617856",
    "white": "821701424047849502",
    "purple": "821701518351663124",
    "brown": "821701610077552670",
    "cyan": "821701791354847232",
    "lime": "821701882011582464"
    }
}
```

its supposed to get the "yellow" id from the json file but doesn't work at all i don't want to use

```js
client.emojis.cache.get(e.yellow)
```

because i would use the skin var to get a random color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.skin`, you tell JavaScript to return property `skin` of the object. If you want to have the property that is in `skin`, you have to use indexing:

```js
let skin2 = client.emojis.cache.get(e[skin]);
```

This will give you the value of the property stored in `skin`.